# Hide ActionSheet iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

My application is about clicking on a button with background image named "uploadphoto1.png". When I click on the button, it shows me an ActionSheet letting me choose to take a picture with the camera or taking a picture from the library.
When, for example, I choose a picture from the camera, it lets me select a picture and show the picture in an imageView and it change the background image of the button from upload.png to save.png.
The problem now that when I click on the button with background Image "save1.png" it shows me the actionSheet.
I want to hide the actionSheet.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 UIImage *buttonpicture =[UIImage imageNamed:@"uploadphoto1.png"];
[ButtonPicture setBackgroundImage:buttonpicture forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ButtonPicture setFrame:CGRectMake(173, 269, 140, 30)];
 }

- (IBAction)ButtonPicture:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSLog(@"Button Picture Pressed");
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Picture From Camera",@"Picture From Gallery",nil];

[actionSheet setTag:1001];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
switch (buttonIndex)
{
    case 0:
    {
        // Take a picture from camera
        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        // take a picture from gallery photos
        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    }
        break;
    default:
    break;    }

   }

   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[ButtonPicture setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"save1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageview.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
//[actionSheet showInView:Nil];

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface YourViewController
{
    BOOL imageChanged;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     imageChanged = NO;
     UIImage *buttonpicture =[UIImage imageNamed:@"uploadphoto1.png"];
     [ButtonPicture setBackgroundImage:buttonpicture forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [ButtonPicture setFrame:CGRectMake(173, 269, 140, 30)];
}

- (IBAction)ButtonPicture:(UIButton *)sender
{
     NSLog(@"Button Picture Pressed");
     UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Photo"        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Picture From Camera",@"Picture From Gallery",nil];

     [actionSheet setTag:1001];
     if (!imageChanged)
          [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:   
        // Take a picture from camera
        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        break;
        case 1:
        // take a picture from gallery photos
        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        break;
        default:
        break;   
     }

 }

 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
       [ButtonPicture setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"save1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       imageChanged = YES;
       [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
       imageview.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways this could be handled. One way is to set a boolean flag when you don't want tapping on the button to bring up the actionSheet. Then, in `- (IBAction)ButtonPicture:(UIButton *)sender` you can check the boolean flag to decide whether or not to create the actionSheet and show it.